# Unable to get the correct OCR text Python

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract

I am trying to read the text from a `.png` file, but unable to get the proper output.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import pytesseract

path_to_tesseract = r"Path_to Tesseract-OCR.exe"

image_path = r"Path to png file"

img = Image.open(image_path)

pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

print(text)
```

The output I'm getting is something like this: `m _ an I: umonfé ‘`

Input `.png` file:

[image: input png file]

The expected output is `LG485169046`

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you using [inRange-thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html)

Steps are:

1. Convert the image into the `hsv` colorspace
2. Set the lower and upper boundaries
3. Use a mask to remove the background

The result will be:

[image]

Output will be:

```
LABGROWN IGI LG485169046
```

If you only want the last part, you could do:

```
>>> print(text.split(" ")[3])
LG485169046
```

Code:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract


# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("KfzeJ.png")

# Resize the image
img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=2, fy=2)

# Convert to the hsv color-space
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Get binary-mask
msk = cv2.inRange(hsv, array([0, 0, 0]), array([179, 255, 80]))
krn = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 3))
dlt = cv2.dilate(msk, krn, iterations=1)
thr = 255 - cv2.bitwise_and(dlt, msk)

# OCR
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr)
print(txt.split(" ")[3])
```

P.S. Pytesseract version: 0.3.8

Answer (score -1):

**Step1**- try to add the "Path_to Tesseract-OCR.exe" to your environment variable.

**Step2-** if step1 not worked try to use passporteye package.

Comment: the tesseract is just unable to get the correct output.

Comment: did you try passporteye it is really usefull for readble zones.Try it and inform me about output.

Comment: Tried to install it using pip install Passporteye, but it gives the erroe `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.`

Comment: you can install using:

Comment: pip install PassportEye

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/PassportEye/

Comment: Still the same error